# Browser is not showing my site using public DNS on Amazon EC2 instance [This site can’t be reached]

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, wordpress, amazon-linux

Couple of weeks back i launched an instance on AWS free tier and i was running a wordpress site, I dont have much knowledge about so i followed all the AWS guide and did this step by step everything was working perfect but today am not able to access my site even using Elastic ip or the public DNS http://ec2-52-59-123-209.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/. However am able to connect with putty using ssh and can see navigate to all my folders and file using filezilla. I dont what could be the reason. Please help me to solve this issue. [See the security groups Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbPB3.png). i also tried restarting httpd and mysql service and last night i also went through rebooting my instance and i was able to access everything but now my site is again down.....

Comment: Issue is with the webserver. One can connect to the server on 80/tcp but HTTP requests time out.

Comment: so how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

```
 Please open 80 port on Amazon EC2 Instance through admin panel then try!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: Yes i already added these rules, http is set to port 80.